# Why data parent update but data child don't update, I use @Input?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

```html
    <data-source-form 
           [data]="this.numberOfDuplicatesSapoWeb"
           (showModal)="showModalSapoWeb($event)"
           (removeConnectSapoWeb)="removeConnectSapoWeb($event)"
           (showModalReplication)="showModalReplicationSapoWeb($event)">
    </data-source-form>
```

```
   export class DataSourceFormComponent implements OnInit{
      public _data:string[]
      get data(): any { return this._data }
      @Input() 
      set data(data:any){
        this._data = data
        console.log(this._data)
      }
      @Output() showModal: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter <string>();
      @Output() removeConnectSapoWeb: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter <string>();
      @Output() showModalReplication: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter <string>();
      public dataReplicationSapoWeb = new MatTableDataSource();
      public displayedColumnsReplicationSapoWeb: string[] = ['taikhoanlienket', 'capnhat', 'huylienket'];
      @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;
      constructor( private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
      ngOnInit() {
        // console.log('OnInit ' + this.data)
        this.paginator._intl.itemsPerPageLabel="Số dự án hiển thị";
        this.dataReplicationSapoWeb = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.data);
        this.dataReplicationSapoWeb.paginator = this.paginator;
      }
      clickShowModal(value){
        this.showModal.emit(value)
      }
      clickShowModalReplication(value) {
        this.showModalReplication.emit(value)
      }
      clickRemoveConnectSapoWeb(value:string) {
        this.removeConnectSapoWeb.emit(value)
      }
    }
```

> This is child component, then parent component Event "removeConnectSapoWeb" update this.numberOfDuplicatesSapoWeb but data at child component dont update.
> Event removeConnectSapoWeb/Add is async

Comment: Does everything else works like the o/p events and other things?

Comment: How are you updating the data in the parent? It looks like it is an array - so if you are just adding / removing / changing elements that are in it, it won't update. In order to actually have the child register an update, you would need to re-assign the field with a new array

Comment: Yes it is an array, I push or splice when adding / removing, It dont update at child component But when I execute a new event it updates again, I don't why?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you set a value to dataReplicationSapoWeb only in ngOnInit, so when you receive a new value of data it doesn't change it's value. Yo need to do this:

```
@Input() 
  set data(data:any){
    this._data = data
    this.dataReplicationSapoWeb = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.data); <- Assign value to DataSource each time you receive new data
  }
```

Comment: Why I update data at parent but 'console.log(this._data)' it not displayed, It only displays once